# Drupal document upload and thumbnail display

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, grid

I have a Drupal 6.2 site and I would like to add a templates section like in the following sites:

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/
- http://www.templatemonster.com/drupal-themes.php
- http://www.dreamweavergraphics.net/drupal_templates.html

I would like the templates organized as a grid and to be tagged/categorized.

Only the admin would be uploading templates.

Would really appreciate any help and advice you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about it this way:

1. Add "template" content type
2. Add cck fields: image, link, etc.
3. Create download folder above the www_root to link to for download
4. Add taxonomy for tagging
5. Create views to display items; optionally you can use panorama/slideshow if you want to mimic some of the sites you have above.
6. Configure permissions for admin only to create content

You can also do this in ubercart if the products have a price, or even if they don't.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I shall have to look up how to add the content type Template and cck fields though

Comment: cck is a module which extends content fields beyond title and description. It is basically a necessity in Drupal 6, and a form of it is included in D7. It allows you to add more fields of any type (text, image, etc) to content types.

Comment: If you don't have the administration menu module installed, install it. Adding a content type is under Content Management>>Content type>> Add content type.